# How to avoid requesting data via ajax before the previous one requested complete in a for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, delay

I would like to send multiple request by using ajax and return to data in a for loop (one by one, one finished, one start...).

However, it seems sometimes it sends a new data without waiting for the previous one completed. as a result, the data returned is not correct. Although it happens not frequently, anyone could help me to solve the problem?

```
for (var i=0; i<myarray.length;i++){
        ajaxfunction(myarray[i]);
    }
```

My assumption is to:

setTimeout in the loop, but the result seems wrong

I have to use RAW javascript, not JQuery or other library. I found a interesting things called "complete:" and ".done()" in JQuery, I am not sure if that is what I want. May anyone tell me how to solve the problem by using raw javascript?

Comment: Do each AJAX call in the callback function of the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use recursive to solve this problem but don't know if it's having bad side or not. The code something like this:

```
function doRequest(index, collection){
    $.ajax({
        url: collection[index],
        ....
        complete: function(){
            //do something
            if (index + 1 < collection.length) doRequest(index + 1, collection);
        }
    });
}

doRequest(0, myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive call did magic to solve the problem of finish one ajax call and wait for another request until first request finished.

```
var queue_element = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"];

var execute_queue = function(i){    
 $.ajax( {    
    url: queue_element[i],
    success: function(
    {
        i++;    // going to next queue entry

        // check if it exists
        if (queue_element[i] != undefined)
        {
            execute_queue(i);
        }
    }

  }); // end of $.ajax( {...

}; // end of execute_queue() {...

var index = 0;

execute_queue(index); // go!
```